# how to change the value of a query returning TRUE/FALSE

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

My form has a 'did you seek medical attention' checkbox that returns value as true or false. I want to print this result out in a form, however i want the value to return 'Did/ Did not seek medical attention' instead of the boolean value. I have this so far:

```
Case when md.seen_doctor = 'FALSE' THEN CAST (md.gweld_doctor AS Varchar(15))
```

I don't know how to assign the different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case when md.seen_doctor = 'FALSE' 
            then 'Did not seek medical attention'
            else 'Did seek medical attention'
       end as res_checkbox
from your_table
```

Comment: I edited the strings the way I think the OP wants them to appear.

Comment: Thanks, seems so simple now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN
          md.seen_doctor = 0
          THEN 'Did not seek medical attention'
          ELSE 'Did seek medical attention'
        end 'Med_Checkbox'
FROM
tbltablename
```